# C sharp project does not run due to gnu make

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, gnu-make

I've cloned a c sharp project, Open Visual Studio-> Open a project or a solution-> Choose project sln-> build it successfully.
When I try to run it  I get the next error( previously I install .NET 3.5 framework ( which was required for this project) I get the next error:

[image]

From what low info's I had : this project was previously created/build in windows 7 ( which I think its still using gnu make).I tried to install gnu make via cmd but its not viable anymore as I know for windows 10
I'm using windows 10 ( and I also use make files using cgywin make for example).
Does some one know how to fix it this and run it? Also I never use c sharp before...

Comment: Which project are you cloning? Perhaps the error message does not come from compiling the project, but an error `MessageBox` via `MessageBox.Show(...., MessageBoxIcon.Error);` (Probably the program requires GNU to function, and that's why it is checking if it is installed and if not, the program will be terminated)

Comment: I agree with @iLittleWizard this error doesn't appear to be a build error but a dependency check that the program runs on startup. I guess it needs GNU make for normal operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for opening my eyes, seems that the error icon was the proram one too  so its exactly the case you mentioned.